# ayuda con consulta Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, wpf, sql-server-2012

Quiero pasar una consulta de sqlserver a linq en c#

Parte de la consulta me funciona bien, cuando hago un join con la otra tabla que necesito y trato de usar el operador `AND` me arroja error, no se si deba usar otro operador anexo ambas consultas.

SQLSERVER:

```
USE SSF_PRUEBAS
select tprtercegener,tgenombcomp 
from un_terceprove inner join un_tercegener on (tprtercegener = tgecodigo and tprcompania = tgecompania)
where tprcompania in ('01','02') and un_terceprove.eobcodigo = 'AC'
```

Linq:

```
private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string proveedor = txtBuscar.Text;
            using(SSF_PRUEBASEntities entidades = new SSF_PRUEBASEntities())
            {
                var query = from p in entidades.un_terceprove.ToList()
                            join c in entidades.un_tercegener 
                            on (p.tprtercegener equals c.tgecodigo && p.tprcompania equals c.tgecompania)
                            where p.tprcompania == 01 && p.eobcodigo == 'AC'
                    select new { p.nit, p.proveedor };   

            }
        }
```

Este es el error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco sus comentarios, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Deberias usar algo como esto

```
 var query = from p in entidades.un_terceprove.ToList()
                join c in entidades.un_tercegener 
                on new {codigo = p.tprtercegener, compania = p.tprcompania} equals new { codigo = c.tgecodigo, compania = c.tgecompania)
                where p.tprcompania == 01 && p.eobcodigo == 'AC'
        select new { p.nit, p.proveedor };
```

observa como se definen objetos anonimos con propiedades que deben coincidir

[Realizar una unión usando claves compuestas](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys)

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, creo que te resultara mas entendible :

```
private void BtnBuscar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      string proveedor = txtBuscar.Text;
      using(SSF_PRUEBASEntities entidades = new SSF_PRUEBASEntities())
      {
           var query = from p in entidades.un_terceprove.ToList()
           join c in entidades.un_tercegener.ToList() 
           on p.tprtercegener equals c.tgecodigo
           where p.tprcompania == 01 && p.eobcodigo == 'AC'
           where p.tprcompania == c.tgecompania
           select new { p.nit, p.proveedor };   
      }
}
```

Comment: porque pones una parte de la definicion de join y la otra como where?, eso es incorrecto, linq soporta join de multiples propiedades

Comment: no es incorrecto, es una manera diferente, y solo doy una manera diferente BLD :D

Comment: lo que planteas es un parche por una limitante en el equals, entonces relacionas una propiedad y bajas la otra al where, leiste el articulo que propuse https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/join-by-using-composite-keys  esta situacion esta contemplada en linq